# rewrite and changes file with admin priviliges

Tags: c#, file, admin, manifest

I try to write into a file that doesn't end with txt while I have admin priviliges.
Therefore I replaced in the menifest the line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
```

To

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

But it didn't work when I run this code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"))
        {
                sw.WriteLine("0.0.0.0    WWW.test.com");
        }
```

I got an error that says I don't have the privileges to changes this file. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTDxY.png)

And when I came back to the menifest file I found that it was changed back, I got a message: "The file has been modifide outside of the sourse editor" [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOaOv.png)

I don't know why it was changed, I know that "requireAdministrator" should gives me admin privilages by asking the user.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but i think requireAdministrator is much more appropriate option for requestedExecutionLevel   in this case.

[http://philippsen.wordpress.com/tag/requestedexecutionlevel-manifest/]

Comment: I try requireAdministrator too and I have the same problem.

Comment: even if u manually run it with right-click "As administrator" ??? May be antivirus or so on???